# CSS - How to use "vertical-align : middle" with a table near an image?

Tags: css

I would like to align an image with a table on the same line.
I have tried to use the `vertical-align : middle` CSS Property but it doesn't work right. the table is not centered with the middle of the image.

```
<div align="center">
    <img src="timing-overview.png" width="800px"/>
    <table border style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;">...</table>
</div>
```

I have tried to replace `inline-block` `display` property by `inline-table` or `table` without any success.

The solution I found is to set a `vertical-align: top` and add these 2 properties : `position: relative` and `top: Xpx`.

But I need to adjust the pixel number from top which is depending of the image and table size.

```
<div align="center">
    <img src="timing-overview.png" width="800px"/>
    <table border style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; position: relative; top: 50px;">...</table>
</div>
```

In my case, the image height is greater than the table height.

Is someone have a idea ?

Regards

Comment: You have to wrap image and table in separate div's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use `display` property for table because it already has property `display: table`. Wrap your table in a div instead and add style `display: inline-block` to that div.

```css
.table-wrap {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

img {
vertical-align: middle;
}

td {
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
 <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/38/21/61/3821618a4005b0b4aaaa741a53f496e9.jpg" width="200px"/>
    
    <div class="table-wrap">
    <table>
      <tr><td>1</td></tr>
      <tr><td>2</td></tr>
      <tr><td>3</td></tr>
      <tr><td>4</td></tr>
      <tr><td>5</td></tr>
     </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `flexbox` to achieve easily what you want. See my example below. The div `.center` has everything in it.

> The **CSS3 Flexible Box**, or **flexbox**, is a layout mode providing
>   for the arrangement of elements on a page such that the elements
>   behave predictably when the page layout must accommodate different
>   screen sizes and different display devices.

Read more about flexbox at [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

```css
.center {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/AzeiaRY.jpg" width="400px"/>
    <table border style="">
      <tr>
        <td>BLALBLALBLALBLALBAL</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```